# Two-way bind an object of the scope of the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a directive that has a two-way binding to the passed object:

```
angular.module('app').directive('lmDataBox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            lmdata: '=',
        },
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="lmdata.displayValue">',
        link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.lmdata.displayValue = 'testvalue';
    }
};
```

However, even though I set "displayValue" to a string the input box is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have found your problem:

lmdata is probably not set in your parent scope. This means that when you try to set scope.lmdata.displayValue you try to set an undefined scope variable.

To solve this you have to set lmdata in your parent scope like so:

```
$scope.lmdata = {'displayValue':''};
```

I have created a working example in plnkr (I only changed the restriction to 'E' for convenience) [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YjxIbJnlNubM4co1IMnF?p=preview)

Comment: This seems like the right answer, but just to nitpick - it's not that `lmdata.displayValue` is not set (that is fine). It's that `lmdata` is not set, and it cannot set the `displayValue` property of `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was the issue. Awesome!